# Redirect https and http in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an old url (`test.me.com`) and I would like to redirect it to `www.me.com`.

So I added this line to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.me\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But as it turns out, Google has already indexed some of the pages. And since I have an SSL Certificate, the full url is `https://test.me.com`.  So the redirect of above won't affect the `https` files...

I've tried this one, but with no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:http]

# redirect urls with index.html to folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.me.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:ps}://www.me.com/%1 [R=302,L]
```

How can I configure my .htaccess file that both `http://test.me.com` and `https://www.test.com` are redirected to `http://www.me.com`?

Answer (score 2):

```
# redirect https requests or request on test.me.com to http://www.me.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.me\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.me.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or alternatively to also redirect me.com to www.me.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.me\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.me.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But shouldn't the second line in your alternative solution be something like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.me\.com$ [NC]`

Comment: Where does the `test.me.com` get redirected?

Comment: Have you noticed the `!` that wasn't there is the first option. The `!` means any hostname that is not `www.me.com`, which would match `test.me.com`.